# How to increment the number in a string while keeping the appropriate trailing/leading zeros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm curious as to how accounting softwares enable incrementing "invoice number" ie from INV-001 increments to INV-002. Let's dissect by only focusing on "001".

I've done some "Googling" and found the use of `"%03d"`:

```rb
puts "%03d" % 1
#=> "001"
```

That's a start, but I struggle with many variations:

```rb
str = "001"
str = "009"
```

At school we were taught:

```rb
# Let's assume we knew nothing about strings
001 + 1 # gives us 002. How?

# This is what really happens
#
#  001
# +  1
# ______
#  002
```

Using the above, if we "add" 009 + 1, we get `010` if we use the above method.

Things are much different with programming as converting "001" to integer becomes `1`.

How can I create a method that knows how to add `"001"` plus `1` which returns `"002"`?

I assume a lot of things are going on with the above formula:

1. How it knows what to add `1` to.
2. How it knows to bring the "remainder" to the left then add ie `009 + 1 = 010`
3. For 3, how it knows to keep a zero at the end `010` and not `10`

I've tried many things but are all incorrect. Basically I need to increment the strings:

```rb
# Result should be when str is incremented by 1
str = "002" + 1 #=> "003"
str = "0002" + 1 #=> "0003"
str = "009" + 1 #=> "010"
str = "0002" + 1 #=> "0010"
str = "02" + 1 #=> "03"
str = "1" + 1 #=> "2"
```

Converting the `str` to float loses the zeros and I cant seem to use any logic successfully with `"%03d"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next` like so:

```
("%03d" % 1).next #=> '002'
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is, the string comes from the user is "002" and I need to increment that so the variation can be one of many ie "0001" at max 10 chars.

Comment: @sylar For completeness sake, the 4th example is more complicated, and you have to actually convert to an integer and back, and I'm not sure how you'd know to use it: `input = "0002"; "%0#{input.length}d" % input.to_i(3).next.to_s(3) #=> "0010"`

Answer (score 4):

> I'm curious as to how accounting softwares enable incrementing "invoice number" ie from INV-001 increments to INV-002.

Accounting software typically doesn't operate on the previously generated string. Instead, it just stores the invoice number (i.e. the numeric part) as an ordinary integer, e.g.:

```
invoice_number = 9
```

It then formats that number according to a small template, e.g.

```
format('INV-%03d', invoice_number)
#=> "INV-009"
```

Now, going from `INV-009` to `INV-010` is simply a matter of incrementing the integer and running it through the formatter:

```
invoice_number += 1
#=> 10

format('INV-%03d', invoice_number)
#=> "INV-010"
```

Comment: You're making this too easy! Thanks for explaining this. Now I can use regular incremental columns.

Comment: @Sylar _"You're making this too easy!"_ – I'll take that as a compliment :-)

Comment: @Sylar: This is a general principle in Software Engineering: correct data modeling (and in OO also correct object modeling) makes the problem *much easier* to solve. In this case, the correct way to model an invoice **number** is as a **number**, not as text. (The name "invoice number" actually already gives it away.) As soon as you model it as a number, doing "number stuff", such as incrementing, becomes trivial.

Comment: But it gets tricky. How to store “002” as number when both “002” and “0002” are different? invoice number is unique in the dB and `“002”.to_i` and `”0002”.to_i` gives same `2`

Comment: @Sylar: Then it's not a number but rather an "invoice identifier object", and you model it as an `InvoiceIdentifier`.